# Is it possible to build APK from a phone?

Tags: android

Is it possible to build APK from source with in an android phone?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/

Currently for native, but some high level libs also there...worth checking

Other projects:
[Cool](http://code.google.com/p/mapsforge/) | [Cooler](http://code.google.com/p/websmsdroid/) | [Coolest](http://code.google.com/p/openintents/)

Answer (score 8):

If you can manage to port the green bubbles to Android, you can get it done. It is not so simple though.

`edit:` Well someone has done this: check the [the other answer](http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/).

- [AAPT](http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/t_arn/JavaIDEdroid/Aapt.java)
- [Compiler call](http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/t_arn/JavaIDEdroid/IDE.java)
- [dex](http://www.google.com/codesearch#SN5sWMy-x8I/trunk/materials/dx/&type=cs) (native)
- [apkBuilder](http://www.google.com/codesearch#pupkm2qsoTw/trunk/autoandroidlib/src/main/java/com/googlecode/autoandroid/lib/AndroidTools.java&q=AndroidTools&type=cs)
- [JarSigner](http://code.google.com/p/java-ide-droid/source/browse/trunk/src/com/t_arn/JavaIDEdroid/SignApk.java)
- [zipAlign](http://www.google.com/codesearch#search&q=zip+package:http://java-ide-droid%5C.googlecode%5C.com)

  [image]