# Is it possible to run Gradle on Android?

Tags: android, gradle

is it possible to build apk on Android? Like it [AIDE](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.aide.ui&hl=br) do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately Gradle is not available for AIDE, on their official website they stated that.

> ***AIDE also supports basic Android Studio projects, which follow the default project structure. The full gradle build system is not yet
>   supported though.***

[Opening Android Studio projects in AIDE](http://www.android-ide.com/tutorial_androidstudio.html)

Comment: Hey, ok I just need to build projects on phone in my app. Have you any good tools. Yup, saw [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7831294/is-it-possible-to-build-apk-from-a-phone) but I need something new:)